# How to implement widget/unit test for responsive UI/widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, widget, flutter-web, flutter-test

I'm new to flutter, and my trying to implement unit and widget testing for my personal project. I need help on implementing the testing when it comes to responsive widgets. For example, I have a widget that is visible in DESKTOP size and is hidden in TABLET/MOBILE size screens. How can I create a test for this scenario?

Note: I'm using [responsive_framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework)